# Get indexes from a vector with multiple elements based on a specific value

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector:

```
lst <- c("2,1","7,10","11,0","7,0","10,0","1,1","1,0","4,0","4,1","0,1","6,0")
```

each element contains two numbers,separated by ",". I would like to get indexes of elements containing "1". 
So the index list is expected:

```
1, 6, 7, 9, 10
```

Comment: One might ask why you're storing the data this way though.  Why not store it in a matrix?

Comment: @Rich Scriven this function doesn't give me the right result. the Index 5 (10,0) is not what I expected.

Comment: What was your code?  You can't just look for 1s because of the 10 in there.  You need to constrict it to start or end with 1, and include the middle comma.  I did `grep("^1,|,1$", lst)` and it works.

Comment: Is it always two values that you have?  You might consider modifying the data to better store what you have.  Something like: `do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(lst, ","), as.numeric))`

Comment: How do you want to handle [multiallelic](http://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/6455/biallelic-vs-multiallelic-sites) variants? i.e.: `c("3,4,1", "4,4", "2,1,3")`

Comment: @zx8754 - For that case, you could change the regex in my answer to `"^1,|,1,|,1$"`. But we might even be able to simplify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep()` will work nicely for this.  By default, it returns the indices of the matched pattern.

```
grep("^1,|,1$", lst)
# [1]  1  6  7  9 10
```

The regular expression `^1,|,1$` looks to match a string that

- `^1,` = starts with `1,`
- `|` OR
- `,1$` = ends with `,1`

Answer (score 0):

each element contains two numbers. my answer is not ideal but I got what I need.

```
m <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(lst), "\\,"),"[[",1)))
n <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(lst), "\\,"),"[[",2)))
sort(unique(c(which(m==1),which(n==1))))
```

Comment: You don't really need all these conversions, neither you need to do it twice, you could just do `which(colSums(sapply(strsplit(lst, ",", fixed = TRUE), `==`, "1")) > 0)` OR you could fully vecotrize this (avoid `sapply`) using something like `which(colSums(matrix(unlist(strsplit(lst, ",", fixed = TRUE)), 2) == "1") > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on background and context of this task it might be prudent to turn this vector into a data.frame:

```
lst <- c("2,1","7,10","11,0","7,0","10,0","1,1","1,0","4,0","4,1","0,1","6,0")
DF <- read.table(text = do.call(paste, list(lst, collapse = "\n")), sep = ",")
which(DF$V1 == 1L | DF$V2 == 1L)
#[1]  1  6  7  9 10
```